# Unable to delete a comment that is a reply to another comment using Youtube API V3

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am attempting to delete a comment with an id value of

```
z13gwx5polebffepe04ch34zhmvfg1czqlo0k.
```

The request returns the following error:

```
{"error"=>
  {"errors"=>
    [{"domain"=>"youtube.comment",
      "reason"=>"processingFailure",
      "message"=>
       "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid.",
      "locationType"=>"parameter",
      "location"=>"id"}],
   "code"=>400,
   "message"=>
    "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid."}}
```

Is there a different API endpoint to delete comments that replies to other comments or is there another parameter that needs to be send along? From the documentation only id appears to be a valid parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To delete any comment, You have to be the commenter of that comment or you have to owner of that video where comment has been done. If you are not than you can't delete that comment. Go to [https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/delete](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/delete#errors) and find yourself.